# load etex with lualatex

Tags: luatex

I am working on my 12 year latex file. I had loaded etex, but wonder if this is still useful together with lualatex?

```
% Description: see https://texfaq.org/FAQ-noroom
%   short summery: The e-TeX extensions do not help with the 
%                  "no room for a new \write" problem, but in other cases
%                  of "no room for a new <thing> "
%                  "It is essential that you load etex before any other packages, 
%                  and reserve any extra inserts immediately:"
\usepackage{etex} 
\reserveinserts{28}
```

Nothing bad happens, but is it has no use I would remove it.

Comment: You should remove it.

Comment: it is not useful even with pdflatex on any system released since 2015.

Comment: `etex` only does nothing bad if you load it late enough that it can do nothing. If you load it early enough it undoes latex's register assigment code so breaking may current uses, but giving maximum compability with legacy documents using `etex.sty` with an old latex system where it was needed

Comment: the link in the code comment has an updated URL with updated text https://texfaq.org/FAQ-noroom

Comment: Thank you for the update. I removed all related code since laulatex now has solved the problem.